# how to appear the image in ember with handlebars

Tags: image, ember.js, helper, handlebars.js

Hello I want to appear the image from code i wrote below but i cant. Any ideas?
I googled and i found that i must use a helper function.

(template)
showallapps.hbs

```
{{#if getappsexist}}
    {{#each app in getapp}}
       {{#each app.app_files}}
        {{#link-to "dashboard" app}}
            <img {{bind-attr src=get_url}} class="img-responsive">
        {{/link-to}}
        {{/each}}
        {{#link-to "dashboard" app}}
            {{app.app_name}}
        {{/link-to}}
```

(controller)
showallapps.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  apps:[],

   getappsexist: function () {
    var appsexist = false;
    if (this.store.all('userapp').content.length > 0) {
        appsexist = true;
    }
    return appsexist;
}.property(),

getapp: function () {
   this.apps = this.store.all('userapp');
   return this.apps;
}.property(),

get_url: function (){  
  var url = 'http://' + JSON.parse(this.apps.content[2]._data.app_files).url;
  return url;  
}.property()

});
```

I have this json.

```
{
    "userapp": [
        {

        }, 
        {  
           "app_files": "{"url":"static.xxx.xxx/data/application/3911efd9-413a-11e1-b5e9-fbed80c8f6ba/eleutheris_epilogis.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","name":"eleutheris epilogis.jpg"}" 
        } 
     ]
}
```

I get these errors:
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {"url":"static.xxx.xxx/data/application/3911efd9-413a-11e1-b5e9-fbed80c8f6ba/eleutheris_epilogis.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","name":"eleutheris epilogis.jpg"}

Comment: Your html is badly malformed in your template, will you show the entire template, or make sure your template is correct?

Comment: my html is ok and works. I just didn 't include it here.

Comment: I'm talking about in your template, it definitely isn't okay in the template, there are closing tags for divs without opening tags...

Comment: Ok i fixed it! Wrong copy paste. Any suggestions?

Comment: We definitely don't want to use the helper.  What's your model look like?  And your json looks like it returns an empty userapp, and possibly in the wrong format, so I'd guess that wouldn't work?

Comment: Replace `<img src="{{get-url}}" class="img-responsive">` with `<img {{bind-attr src=get-url}} class="img-responsive">`

Answer (score 1):

You need to form the image url as a property of some type in your controller (as you did with the `getUrl` computed property).  Then you can bind to that by doing something like this:

```
<img {{bind-attr src=getUrl}} class="img-responsive" />
```